# Accelerated pixel array rendering in Java

Tags: java, arrays, rendering, bufferedimage, pixel

I have been working on a game that uses a `BufferedImage` to render to the screen. The `BufferedImage` is created from an array of hexadecimal colors. So rendering a rectangle to the screen might look like this:

```
public void renderRectangle (int xl, int yl, int rWidth, int rHeight, int color, double dist) {
    for (int x = xl; x < xl + rWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = yl; y < yl + rHeight; y++) {
            pixels [x + y * WIDTH] = color; //set pixel's color. 
            zBuffer [x + y × WIDTH] = dist; //set pixel's distance from camera.
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, after doing these calculations, especially when rendering in 3d, it gets pretty laggy.

But games such as doom  (which also don't use the gpu) run fine.
So how can I render these graphics without opengl and without lag?

Comment: If you want accelerated rendering in Java, it is crucial to *not touch* the pixel array... See [Managed Images and Performance](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/managed_images.html) and  [VolatileBufferedToolkitImage Strategies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-141909.html) for some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the above code itself is not going to be your performance problem. sure, you could optimize drawing that rectangle in some way (e.g. have rectangles you need often precalculated) but this is not going to  affect performance.

could you probably show some excerpts of how your rendering method (do you create a new buffered image for every frame you render? --> that would be your performance problem then). also are you sure that the problem is really with the rendering and not with triggering the repaints of the screen?

in terms of doom (1), please also consider that it was VGA (320x200 pixels only) and had a very simplified 3d engine, that was based on doing simple matrix transformation on rectangles. also the engine had a lot of logic to decide which areas of the world map were actually visible on screen (and not behind the camera or hidden behind another wall) and only rendered these parts.

given the little information in you question, i hope that this will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: My game runs at 400x150 blown up to fit the screen (as doom does). The buffered image was created at the creation of the display, sí only once. The only conclusión I could make was doom is created in C, which is a much lower level language.

Comment: That is not neccessarily the issue. Do you change the screen resolution to 400x150 Pixels or do you scale the image up? If the latter is the case then this will very likely be your performance problem

Comment: I scale up the image to fit the window.

Comment: then the first attempt to optimize is to run your game in a window that has 400x150 pixels (so no scaling happens). if it runs fast in that case, then your problem is the upscaling. If that is the problem, then what you could do is to either try to change the screen resolution (programmatically) to something smaller. Regardless of the size of your origin image, the upscaling will have to calculate all the pixels that are on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

For the 2D methods like the one you provided, not much can be done; only a little micro-optimization.

```
public void renderRectangle(int xl, int yl, int rWidth, int rHeight, int color) {
    if (rWidth <= 0 || rHeight <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    int pos = xl + yl * WIDTH;
    for (int i = pos, i2 = pos + rWidth; i != i2; i++) {
        pixels[i] = color;
    }
    int pos2 = pos;
    for (int y = 1; y != rHeight; y++) {
        pos2 += WIDTH;
        System.arraycopy(pixels, pos, pixels, pos2, rWidth);
    }
}
```

To improve performance you can try e.g.:

- Precheck that everything is actually visible on screen to avoid useless process
- Make lookup tables for everything that can be precalculated (if you limit colors, can be done even for them)
- Also precalculate  things such as shading